# Issues with resize function, navigation opens then closes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

## Problem

- When the page is at full width, resized to less than 1300px and then
  the hamburger menu is clicked, **the menu unexpectedly opens and then
  closes.**

## Objective

- I want to be able to resize the page, click the hamburger menu and then have the navigation toggle open and then clicking it again will toggle it closed.

### CodePen: https://codepen.io/onlyandrewn/pen/eWVOPQ

### scripts.js

```
  if ($(window).width() < 1300) {
    $(".fa-bars").on("click", function(){
      $(".test").slideToggle();

      if ($(".test").hasClass("is-open")) {
        $(".test").removeClass("is-open");
      } else {
        $(".test").addClass("is-open");
      }
    });
  }

  $(window).on("resize", function(){
      if ($(".test").hasClass("is-open")) {
        $(".test").removeClass("is-open");
        $(".test").hide();
      }

      if ($(window).width() < 1300) {
        $(".fa-bars").on("click", function(){
          $(".test").slideToggle();
        });
      }
  });
```

## index.html

```
<nav id="top">
    <div class="nav__title">
        <a href="/schools/" class="link--title"><h1>School Guide</h1></a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav__wrapper">
        <div class="nav__list--wrapper">

            <div class="nav__hamburger">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <ul class="test">
                    <a href="/schools/about" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>About</li></a>
                    <a href="/schools/all-schools"><li class="item-schools">Schools</li></a>
                    <ul class="inner-text inner-school">
                        <a href="/schools/search/?school_type=Elementary&county=none&distance=" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Elementary</li></a>
                        <a href="/schools/search/?school_type=Middle&county=none&distance=" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Middle</li></a>
                        <a href="/schools/search/?school_type=High&county=none&distance=" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> High</li></a>
                    </ul>

                    <a href="/schools/all-districts" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>Districts</li></a>
                    <li>MAP Scores</li>
                    <ul class="inner-text">
                        <a href="/schools/school-map-scores/" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> By school</li></a>
                        <a href="/schools/district-map-scores/" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> By district</li></a>
                    </ul>

                </ul>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav__list">
                <a href="/schools/about/" class="nav__link"><li class="nav__item item--about">About</li></a>
                <li class="nav__item item--schools">Schools
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                    <ul class="nav__dropdown dropdown--schools">
                        <div class="triangle triangle-schools"></div>
                        <a href="/results.html?filter=elementary" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>Elementary</li></a>
                        <a href="/results.html?filter=middle" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>Middle</li></a>
                        <a href="/results.html?filter=high" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>High</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <a href="/schools/all-districts/" class="nav__link"><li class="nav__item item--districts">Districts</li></a>
                <li class="nav__item item--map">MAP Scores
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                    <ul class="nav__dropdown dropdown--districts">
                        <div class="triangle triangle-map"></div>
                        <a href="/schools/school-map-scores/"><li>By school</li></a>
                        <a href="/schools/district-map-scores/"><li>By district</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="nav__social">
            <div class="nav__icons">
                <a href="" class="link--nav link--facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="link--nav link--twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="link--nav link--envelope" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: do you realize that both click events will be attached and each time you resize they will add more events. The events do not get replaced. Add one click event and do logic inside based on the width.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a code snippet. I've added a link to a CodePen with a working example: https://codepen.io/onlyandrewn/pen/eWVOPQ

Comment: can you explain a bit better what you want to achieve? So normally clicking you open it, clicking again you close it. 
What about the connection with resize?  What should happen on resize? Please provide both cases, if the menu is already open when resizing and if it is not

Comment: a) When the page is less than 1300px, clicking the hamburger menu will toggle the menu open and clicking it again will toggle it closed.

b) When the menu is open, resizing the page will close the menu

c) When the page starts at full width, then is resized to less than 1300px and then the hamburger menu is clicked, toggle the menu open, clicking it again should toggle it closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what's happening is that when your page is less than `1300px`, the `onclick` event in the 1st if i.e. `if ($(window).width() < 1300)` gets bound. Then when you resize, the second event in the `$(window).on("resize", function(){` resize function gets bound.
So on one click, these 2 events first open, then close the menu simultaneously. You need to correct this and make sure only 1 event gets bound. Maybe `unbind` one of the clicks before applying the second using `$( "#foo" ).unbind( "click", handler );`.

Updated your [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmQJgv)

Comment: Do you mind sharing a code snippet. I've added a link to a CodePen with a working example: codepen.io/onlyandrewn/pen/eWVOPQ

Answer (score -1):

can you try this code?

```
    $(".fa-bars").on("click", function(){


    if ($(window).width() < 1300) {         
      $(".test").slideToggle();
      if ($(".test").hasClass("is-open")) {
        $(".test").removeClass("is-open");
      } else {
        $(".test").addClass("is-open");
      }
     }
    });

  $(window).on("resize", function(){
      if ($(".test").hasClass("is-open")) {
        $(".test").removeClass("is-open");
        $(".test").hide();
      }

      if ($(window).width() < 1300) {
        $(".fa-bars").on("click", function(){
          $(".test").slideToggle();
        });
      }
  });
```

Comment: you're adding event handler in condition, that is creating issue. if you can create fiddle I would debug the code for you and fix the bug. thank you

Comment: Here's the link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/onlyandrewn/pen/eWVOPQ

Comment: What did you end up changing by the way? I still see a problem.

Comment: try now, didn't saved.

Comment: I still see it opening and closing twice on resize.

Comment: can you check now?